# Is there any statistical problem on instrumental variable analysis with binary exposure and binary outcome?

Tags: r, stata, binary-data, instrumental-variables

I would like to conduct an instrumental variable (IV) analysis (a.k.a Mendelian Randomization analysis due to my IV is a genetic variant).

In many cases as I searched before, an IV analysis was implemented with both of exposure and outcome were continuous variable. Sometimes continuous exposure and binary outcome were used with ivprobit package in STATA or R software.

On the other hand, my study design is, for example, the association between smokinig status (Ever/Never-binary) and cancer incidecne (binary). In aiddtion, an instrumental variable is a genetic variant.

Therefore, I want to conduct IV analysis with binary exposure and binary outcome. However, I have not seen the analysis with binary exposure and binary outcome based on STATA or R software.

So, is there any statistical problem on an IV analysis with both of binary exposure and outcome? I have a trouble finding the information on this method in a few days.

If it's possible, please let me know what package can be used in this study design (STATA or R, anything is fine).